Next.js API POST method doesn't show data in endpoint
When I'm trying to make a POST request from my frontend side in Next.js project (with TypeScript), my API endpoint doesn't show desired JSON data, but only empty hyperlink string leading to nowhere.

My code for API is located as needed in pages/api/ folder inside project:
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    const data = req.body;
    console.log('from ui', data);
    res.status(200).json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
}

Frontend part:
fetch(`/api/checked-projects`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(updatedCheckedProjects)
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Failed to post project data.');
        }
      })
      .then((data: any) => {
        console.log('Received data:', data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

However, console.log('from ui', data); prints JSON data:
from ui { data: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }

Even more strange is that when I put this data as hardcoded into res.status(200).json({ data: [1, 2, 3, 4] });, the data is shown in endpoint alright.

Try to fix your server side code by the following:
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
try {
    const data = req.body;
    console.log('from ui', data);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
    res.status(200).json(jsonString);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
}

}

Unfortunately, not working. Now it shows "\"\"" in endpoint
